# Accessing DOM object properties from Chrome's content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi, content-script

I ran into a strange problem with a content script. The content script is defined as `"run_at" : "document_end"` in the manifest. After a page is loaded the script inserts an object tag into the page (if the tag with predefined id does not exist yet), and sets some properties in it, such as `type`, `width`, `height`, `innerHTML`, and `title`. All works fine here.

```
function checkForObject()
{
  var obj = document.getElementById("unique_id");
  if(obj == null)
  {
    var d = document.createElement("object");
    d.id = "unique_id";
    d.width = "1";
    d.height = "1";
    d.type = "application/x-y-z";
    d.title = "1000";
    d.style.position = "absolute";
    d.style.left = "0px";
    d.style.top = "0px";
    d.style.zIndex = "1";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d);
  }
}

checkForObject();
```

I see the new object in the page html-code with proper values in its properties.

Some time later I need to read the `title` property of the object in the same content script. The code is simple:

```
function ReadTitle()
{
  var obj = document.getElementById("unique_id");
  var value = obj.title; // breakpoint
  console.log(value);
  // TODO: want to use proper title value here
}
```

The function is called from background.html page:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(
function(info)
{
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(info.tabId, {code: 'setTimeout(ReadTitle, 250);'});
});
```

Unfortunately, in `ReadTitle` I'm getting not what I expect. Instead of current value of the `title` I see the logged value is:

```
function title() { [native code] }
```

If I set a breakpoint at the line marked by `// breakpoint` comment, I see in the watcher that all object properties including the `title` are correct. Nevertheless, the variable `value` gets the abovementioned descriptive string.

Apparently, I have missed something simple, but I can't figure it out.

**The answer**. It was a bug in the npapi plugin, which hosts the object of used type. My apologies for all who have read the question with intention to help.

Comment: That's not even close to enough information to duplicate the problem. My scripts set and get properties, including `title` all day. (1) What is the code that **sets** `title`? (2) What is the target page (exact URL is best)? (3) What version of Chrome are you using? (4) What OS? (5) Link to, or post, the complete script.

Comment: @BrockAdams, Target pages are different. The script is intended to work on all pages (matches "*://*/*" in the manifest). I'm adding more code right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPAPI plugin used in the object erroneously reported `title` as supported method.